GridDB Error 20002 SYNC_SERVICE_ENCODE_MESSAGE_FAILED: Processing Cluster Message Failed - Insufficient Memory?
I'm working with GridDB in a clustered environment, and I encountered the following error when trying to perform operations on the cluster:
20002 SYNC_SERVICE_ENCODE_MESSAGE_FAILED ERROR
Processing of cluster message failed. Memory may be insufficient.
Insufficient memory may be one possible reason. Check if there is sufficient memory space in the system.

I'm running a distributed setup with three nodes, and the issue arises intermittently during high-load operations involving large data inserts. Below is a simplified version of the code I'm using to insert data into a container:
import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.*;

public class GridDBClusterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Connect to the GridDB cluster
            GridStoreFactory factory = GridStoreFactory.getInstance();
            GridStore gridStore = factory.getGridStore(new Properties() {{
                put("notificationAddress", "239.0.0.1");
                put("notificationPort", "31999");
                put("clusterName", "myCluster");
                put("user", "admin");
                put("password", "admin");
            }});

            // Create a container
            ContainerInfo containerInfo = new ContainerInfo();
            containerInfo.setName("SampleContainer");
            containerInfo.setType(ContainerType.COLLECTION);
            containerInfo.setRowKeyAssigned(true);
            containerInfo.setColumnInfoList(Arrays.asList(
                new ColumnInfo("id", GSType.STRING),
                new ColumnInfo("value", GSType.INTEGER)
            ));

            // Create container and add rows
            Container<?, Row> container = gridStore.putContainer(containerInfo);
            container.put(new Row() {{
                setString(0, "key1");
                setInteger(1, 123);
            }});
            container.close();

            gridStore.close();
        } catch (GSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


GridDB version: 4.5.0
Node configuration: 3-node cluster (4 GB RAM each, 50 GB disk)
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
JVM: OpenJDK 11
The error occurs more frequently under heavy insert loads (e.g., bulk inserts).
Restarting the GridDB service temporarily resolves the issue, but it returns during subsequent high-load operations.
Memory usage appears to spike during the process, but I can't pinpoint the exact cause.
What causes the SYNC_SERVICE_ENCODE_MESSAGE_FAILED error in GridDB, and is it always related to insufficient memory?
Are there specific configurations or best practices to optimize memory usage in a clustered GridDB environment?
Could there be an issue with the Java client code or the way I'm handling container operations that contributes to this error?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
